# How to eliminate stiff foam from kegerator?

Tags: kegging, kegerator

I have a kegerator that holds two, five gallon kegs.  The kegs are charged at 25 psi CO2 for two weeks at 70°F (21°C).  When I place a keg in the kegerator I release the pressure on the keg.  Once placed in the kegerator the kegs are set to 8 psi at 40°F (4°C).

When I pour the beer a head of both stiff and soft foam forms.  The soft foam eventually dissipates into beer.  The stiff foam holds it's shape.  I generally remove the stiff foam with a spoon and then pour more beer into the glass to fill it.

I have tried various levels of CO2, as low as 6 psi in the keg (40°F) and 20 psi to charge (70°F).  This has not changed the fact that there is stiff foam.  This happens consistently across multiple styles of beer.

The lines from the keg to the tap are 1/4 inch wide (id), and 10 feet long.  They are stored coiled, horizontally, above the top the kegs.

How can I prevent the stiff foam from forming?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I would say the beer is over carbonated from the start.** Usually 2 weeks at serving pressure 12-14psi at any temp is good for 5 gallon kegs.

Your lines could use some adjusting to pour at the same average psi for most styles 12-14psi. Right now your lines will pour a pint in about 6 seconds at 8 psi. Most will shoot for about 8-10 seconds at a higher serving pressure. To avoid the beer from going below style cO2 volumes while on tap.

So.. long carb at the proper pressure for desired volumes. If you want to rush the force carb only do 25 psi for a day or so.

Then fix your line length and diameter for better pours at a proper serving pressure.

[Determining Proper hose length for your Kegerator](http://www.mikesoltys.com/2012/09/17/determining-proper-hose-length-for-your-kegerator/)

Comment: I am testing this method on the latest kegs and will accept or update the question accordingly once I have results.